# VBA - Same if statement is used multiple times

Tags: vba, excel

I have a long If statement that I am using in multiple for loops and I was wondering if there was a way to shorten my code.

I know in other languages you can store the if statement as a function and call it again and again i.e. Function age() then call it age(), but when I tried to do that in VBA it didn't work.

Does anyone have any ideas? I am using VBA in Excel.

Thanks Sandra

```
For Each var In pan8

        If (pan2.Item(var) <= 15) And (pan3.Item(var) = "F") Then
                If (pan.Item(var) = 21) Then
                    R21F1 = R21F1 + 1
               ElseIf (pan.Item(var) = 22) Then
                    R22F1 = R22F1 + 1
               ElseIf (pan.Item(var) = 23) Then
                    R23F1 = R23F1 + 1
              ElseIf (pan.Item(var) = 24) Then
                    R24F1 = R24F1 + 1
              ElseIf (pan.Item(var) = 25) Then
                   R25F1 = R25F1 + 1
             ElseIf (pan.Item(var) = 26) Then
                   R26F1 = R26F1 + 1
            ElseIf (pan.Item(var) = 27) Then
                   R27F1 = R27F1 + 1
            ElseIf (pan.Item(var) = 28) Then
                   R28F1 = R28F1 + 1
            ElseIf (pan.Item(var) = 29) Then
                   R29F1 = R29F1 + 1
            ElseIf (pan.Item(var) = 31) Then
                    R31F1 = R31F1 + 1
               End If
```

The code continues for 15 different "If (pan2.Item(var) <= 15) And (pan3.Item(var) = "F") Then"

And I call this long bit of code (which is about 5 pages in word) 4 different times.

So I want to be able to store this in something, a friend suggested a function, to be able to call instead of rewriting it each time.

Comment: Show the code you are trying. Also, take a look at Select Case

Comment: Why won't it work in VBA? can you show us what you're trying to do?

Comment: Ill post a part of it in a second (its quite long). 

Essentially when I tried to create a function, it wouldnt let me do it in a sub and then when I created one outside of a sub it wouldnt let me call it.

Comment: You can definitely store an if statement as a function in VBA.

Comment: @Sandra No, you wouldn't be able to create a function within a sub, they have to be declared separately. Store the function in a module, and make it public. You should be able to call it from everywhere then.

Comment: Please post a minimal working example demonstrating your question.

Comment: I just posted some in my original post. 

I will try to make it a public function.

Comment: Dude. Stop. Anytime you start numbering your variables you should be thinking ***loop***. I'm asumming you come from a *Functional* background. Unfortunately, VBA is a *Procedural* language, not a Functional one. You can't do what you want to do, but there are other options. A `select case` and/or a loop are likely what you need, but there's not enough context here to help.

Comment: what is pan8 and R?F? cell or range? could you not use `set`. Looping would serve your purpose as @RubberDuck stated.

Comment: Does your existing code work??

Comment: My code works. It just is very long and I am trying to clean it up, but it does what I want it to do. Its close to 100 pages when in microsoft word but only takes a min to run.

Comment: This is also the first project I have done in VBA so I do not know what exactly it can do.

Comment: Okay, there's a site dedicated just to that, but we'll need your [***full, compilable, working code***](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) or it won't be on topic. Please post your code for review on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and I will help you clean it up. Please note that if it's broken, it will be closed.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely store your code in a function or another sub (are the variables called `R22F1`, `R32F1` etc. or you maybe mean `Range("R22F1")`?).

Please note that I'm using a "Sub" rather than a function, since (whatever R22F1, R23F1 etc. are) you want to automatize an action and not return a value. Assuming that they are code variables:

```
Sub Main()
     MyLongProcedure MyParameter
End Sub

Sub MyLongProcedure(ByVal MyParameter As Integer)
     Select Case MyParameter
         Case 21:
             R21F1 = R21F1 + 1
         Case 22:
             R22F1 = R22F1 + 1 
     End Select
End Sub
```

Please note that you will be able to call the "MyLongProcedure" as many times as you want, without copying and pasting the code but just writing `Call MyLongProcedure()`and passing in it the parameter you want to evaluate to perform the actions accordingly.

**MOREOVER**
If they are ranges named like that, seen the connection between the number you evaluate and the variable in your sample code, why you don't just write a statement of kind `Range("R" & pan & "F1") = Range("R" & pan & "F1") + 1` without need to check with an if or a select case?

Comment: Please, don't use `Call` - just *call* the procedure. `Call` is but a relic from an ancient version of VB.

Comment: R22F1 is a variable

Later on I put those variables into cells then reset them to zero before then next loop. 

Essentially the for loop is counting the number of people who fit the parameters. So the first is a female under 15 who lives in Region 21.

Comment: @retailcoder is surely right, it's been some time i dont code anymore in vb. Remove the Call keyword from my example, i will do it from my post

Comment: @Matteo When deleting the `Call` you broke your code by leaving the brackets!  Fixed it for you..

Comment: Thanks @chris, sorry but didnt get really time to try the code and the last time i wrote a call to a macro it was as Call Macro(par). Sorry about that, and thanks for the edit... I have learned a new thing today

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, all you're really asking is the syntax for calling functions/procedures in VBA.

To call a procedure in VBA, you simply refer to its name, without the parentheses; so `Sub Foo()` can be called/executed like this:

```
Foo
```

If `Foo` had parameters, say `Sub Foo(ByVal bar As String)`, then you just add the arguments after the procedure's name (separated by commas if there's more than one):

```
Foo "bar"
```

Now, say you want the procedure to *return a value*, and that you want to use that value at the call site, you'd use a *function* instead: `Function Foo(ByVal bar As String) As Boolean`

And call it *with* parentheses:

```
Dim result As Boolean
result = Foo("bar")
```

If the function has no parameters, the parentheses are optional.

Using parentheses when calling a `Sub`, is illegal syntax.